http4s request with multipart/form-data sending empty content
I am attempting to make a request using http4s client to send a file payload which is Array[Byte] as a multipart form request. There doesn't seem to be any mention of this functionality in the docs.
I have tried to do something like this
def main():IO[Unit] = {
        filename           = "example.txt"
        fieldName          = "payload"
        fileEntityBody     = fs2.Stream.emits(extract).covary[IO] //extract is an array of bytes


        multipart = Multipart[IO](
                      Vector(
                        Part.fileData(
                          fieldName,
                          "",
                          fileEntityBody,
                          Headers.of(Header("Content-Disposition", s"""form-data; name="$fieldName"; filename="$filename""""))
                        )
                      )
                    )

        makeRequest(parsedUri, headers, multipart, Method.PUT)

}

 def makeRequest(
        parsedUri: Either[ParseFailure, Uri],
        headers: Headers,
        requestPayload: Multipart[IO],
        method: Method
    ): IO[Unit] = {
      for {
        uri     <- IO.fromEither(parsedUri)
        request <- IO(
                     Request[IO](method, uri)
                       .withHeaders(headers)
                       .withEntity(requestPayload)
                   )
        _       <- client.run(request).use(response_ => IO(responseHandler(response_)))

      } yield IO.unit
    }

However when looking at the raw request made by http4s i see the following sent to the server
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
content-length: 0
host: 10.10.10.10:8000
accept: */*
user-agent: AHC/2.

Indicating that http4s is not evaluating the multipart payload as content length is 0 -- any suggestions what can be wrong?
